# bootstrap find element inside active tab by classname shown event.

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to find element inside the current tab with classname as myelement on the shown event of bootstrap tab.
using ".myelement" will give me all elements which i do not want.

https://jsfiddle.net/dcdtkubt/4/

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p class="myelement">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p  class="myelement">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p  class="myelement">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p  class="myelement">Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
    $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){
        var x = $(event.target).text();         // active tab
        var y = $(event.relatedTarget).text();  // previous tab
        console.log($(event.target));
        console.log($(".myelement")); // Want to find this inside the selected tab.

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

class tab pane is active based on the tab selected; Make use of it

```
$(".tab-pane.active .myelement"))
```

Comment: What if there is more than one Tab on page? This solution would fail

Comment: Or you can add a property to your anchor tags and access the child accordingly

Here is the updated fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/dcdtkubt/7/

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

```
$(".myelement",$(event.target).attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Loop through `li` elements and find the index of the `active` one.
Step 2: Use the calculated index to access the content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
});
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){
    var x = $(event.target).text();         // active tab
    var y = $(event.relatedTarget).text();  // previous tab
    console.log($(event.target));
    // Initialize index 
    var index = -1;
    // Find the index of active tabs
    var tabs = $(".nav li").each(function(i) {
        if(index === -1 && $(this).hasClass('active')) {
        index = i;
      }
    });
    // Access calculated index of active tab
    console.log($(".myelement")[index]); // Want to find this inside the selected tab.

});
```

});

Comment: This will not work for multiple tabs in a single page.